# React: Why is my state undefined on the initial render from useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

useEffect does render the data from the axios get request. However in the console it logs the initial results as an empty array. `const childRefs = useMemo(() => new Array(results.length).fill(0).map((i) => React.createRef()),[]);` This line requires the results state to return with the array from the axios request otherwise I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of undefined`  . If I pass the results state as an argument in useEffect then useEffect keeps calling without stoping. How do I get the results state set on the initial render without useEffect calling indefinitely?

```
export default function SwipePage() {

  const [ results, setResults ] = useState([]);
  const [ isOpen, setIsOpen ] = useState(false);

  const { userState, setUserState } = useContext(UserContext);

  const { id } = useParams();

  const api = `http://localhost:5000/user/match/${id}`;

  const alreadyRemoved = [];

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(api, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: localStorage.getItem("jwt"),
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setResults(res.data.user);
        console.log(results, "Results")
      });
  }, []);

const childRefs = useMemo(() => new Array(results.length).fill(0).map((i) => React.createRef()),[]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With useMemo you will get a memoized result. Put the results into the dependency array of useMemo and your data will be recalculated if the results state was changed.

```
const childRefs = useMemo(() => new Array(results.length).fill(0).map((i) => React.createRef()),[results]);
```

Comment: Hero! Thank you!